# KO.js model binding. Calling a function in the viewmodel from a grand child is not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel, model-binding

I have the following model binding.

```
    <!-- ko foreach: RctApplyVacancy.RctVacancies -->
    <tr>
        // Some TD elements
        // Following binding works
        <td class="rct-vmiddle text-center" style="width: 8%;">
            <input type="button" data-bind="click: RctApplyVacancy.Apply" />
        </td>
        <td class="rct-vmiddle text-center" style="width: 4%;">
            <a data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="right"
               type="button" data-html="true" href="#" data-bind="attr: { id: 'Share' + AdvId() }">
                <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'popover-content' + AdvId() }" class="hide">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li data-bind="click : RctApplyVacancy.Apply">
                        <i class="classes" aria-hidden="true"></i></li> // This won't
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

As per the comments, the binding, at the latter half (please follow the comment `This won't`) is not working. Could someone please explain me why? What am I doing wrong here?

P.S Please request additional details in comments if needed. I have omitted the ViewModel for the sake of clarity.

Comment: *"I have omitted the ViewModel for the sake of clarity."* *Brevity*, maybe; not clarity. (Next time, include a [mcve] of it.)

Comment: Oops! Wrong choice of words. :D Yups it is brevity.. Thanks for the tip..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a problem with [Bootstrap's popover plugin](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/). As it is seen in the question, `<li data-bind="click : RctApplyVacancy.Apply">` is contained in a `<div>` that looks like `<div data-bind="attr: { id: 'popover-content' + AdvId() }" class="hide" id="popover-content6"> ... </div>` once rendered. This ID in a different place in the app, is used to generate a popover using Bootstrap's popover plugin.

I have tried running this without the part `data-bind="attr: { id: 'popover-content' + AdvId() }" class="hide"` (i.e. `<div>` tag in its plain looks). That worked flawless. I tried with the aforesaid content, it didn't work. It seems like, popover strips off the model bindings, making the bindings of the children to functions are no more functional. However **this appears to have no effect on data bindings in the children**. Every data bindings appears to work.

**EDIT1**
The last sentence above seems to be invalid. Because even though there is a binding that appears, its values seems to be incorrect. Await further facts.

Answer (score 0):

[`foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) makes the item for the iteration the current item and resolves relative to it. See [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), if you want to refer to the parent item (or its parent), you use `$parent` (or `$parents[1]` for the grandparent item). Looking at your markup, I'd say you want `$parent.RctApplyVacancy.Apply`.